# Multiple images via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm rather new to this and currently have two instances of:

```
    var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('Latest_A');

img.onload = function() {
  Latest_A.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = '../Latest_A.jpg';
```

(Then another, B and so forth)

Currently it's only calling the last instance? Anyway to call both or more?

Comment: Can you show all of the JS if there is more and any html as well? I would suggest replicating your issue in a snippet or on jsfiddle.

Comment: Your variable (that holds the element) is called `div`, not `Latest_A`. So `div.appendChild(img);`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you are attempting to add multiple images to the same `<div>` element from a list of image URLs.

This will take a list of URLs from an array and add each to a selected div. IT will also assign each a unique id in case you need to style each.

```js
   var div = document.getElementById('Latest_A');

   var imageArray = ['http://placehold.it/200x200','http://placehold.it/200x300','http://placehold.it/300x200','http://placehold.it/200x150'];

   for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.id = 'image' + i;
   img.src = imageArray[i];
   div.appendChild(img);
   }
```

```html
   <div id="Latest_A"></div>
```

Comment: You sir are amazing! Thank you!